# How to put Nextcloud in kubernetes in maintenance mode

Tags: kubernetes, nextcloud, openebs

I'm trying to migrate my Nextcloud instance to a kubernetes cluster. I've succesfully deployed a Nextcloud instance using **openEBS-cStor** storage. Before I can "kubectl cp" my old files to the cluster, I need to put Nextcloud in maintenance mode.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Shell access to pod
- Navigate to folder
- Run OCC command to put next cloud in maintenance mode

These are the commands I used for the OCC way:

```sh
kubectl exec --stdin --tty -n nextcloud nextcloud-7ff9cf449d-rtlxh -- /bin/bash
su -c 'php occ maintenance:mode --on' www-data
# This account is currently not available.
```

Any tips on how to put Nextcloud in maintenance mode would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `su` command fails because there is no shell associated with the `www-data` user.

What worked for me is explicitly specifying the shell in the `su` command:

```sh
su -s /bin/bash www-data -c "php occ maintenance:mode --on"
```