# How to create an alias for Kubernetes Nextcloud "occ" command in .bashrc

Tags: bash, kubernetes, alias, nextcloud

So, I have a microk8s Kubernetes cluster running Nextcloud, and I want to run "occ" commands directly from the host, without the need to drill-down into the pod terminal.

eg:
`occ maintenance:mode --on` where **occ** is actually `microk8s kubectl exec -it nextcloud-dev-6f6f5db6f7-5rtm9 -- su -s /bin/bash www-data -c "php occ"`

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70823293/5484185), I actually got very close, but I am having problems to pass arguments to the alias.

This is my entry on .bashrc:

```
alias occ='microk8s kubectl exec -it nextcloud-dev-6f6f5db6f7-5rtm9 -- su -s /bin/bash www-data -c "php occ $1"'
```

My guess is that the double quotes is messing with the argument, but not sure how to solve it.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
This question was marked as duplicated based on [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter), and the answer is indeed buried there, and not tailored for my needs. The question in the other post is also misleading, as commented in one of its responses that explains my understanding of an `alias` that is: [...alias just adds a second name for something that already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34670873/5484185), and I would never have clicked on it because that discussion was out of context in regards what I was looking for.
What I needed was the answer provided by [hyperupcall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75411244/5484185) **(THANK YOU FOR THAT!)**, which used the same solution from [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter), but within the context that includes Nextcloud, bashrc, and Kubernetes in the same sentence.
I believe that this makes this question **different enough** to **NOT** be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Use a function instead of an alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function:

```bash
occ() {
  microk8s kubectl exec -it nextcloud-dev-6f6f5db6f7-5rtm9 -- su -s /bin/bash www-data -c "php occ $*"
}
```

You cannot use variables like `$1` inside of aliases and have them work like you think they do. Arguments after alises are simply appended on at the end, so you need to use a function.

Comment: That does not work if one of the parameters passed to `occ` has a space in it. E.g. `occ notification:generate username "This is a notification message"` will not work, because the message parameter itself has spaces in it.